# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 when connecting Flask and D3.js

Tags: javascript, sqlite, flask, d3.js, flask-sqlalchemy

Created a SQLite database and tried to connect to it using flask.

**This is the flask app**

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///data/msa.sqlite")
    conn = engine.connect()
    session = Session(bind=engine)
    data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM msa", conn)
    data_json = json.loads(data.to_json(orient='records'))
    session.close()

    return render_template("index.html", data=data_json)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**This is the JavaScript file where I try to access the data by doing a console.log**

```
d3.json("/").then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);

});
```

**This is the folder structure**

```
|-->flask_app.py
    |-->static
        |-->js
            |-->index.js
    |-->templates
        |-->index.html
```

**I get the following errors when try to load them**

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico 404 (NOT FOUND)
VM1428:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I try using jsonify instead but gave me another different error. I am able to access the data if I just try to access it directly in the html file by doing this:

```
          {% for info in data %}
            <li style="color:blue">This incident happened in the state of  {{ info.state }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
```

I have tried multiple things but nothing seems to work. This seems to be a data type issue. By ready a lot about this error, it sounds like d3.json(..) is trying to access the html and not the json based on this error (Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

Comment: Yes, it's definitely accessing the HTML. Have you tried just returning `data_json` from `index`? d3 should be able to use that. You can also create a separate endpoint that returns the JSON data, and then use that as the path for the JSON data for d3.

Comment: @Nisala Yes, I am able to return just the json but then I do not have access to the html file to render it.

Comment: I recommend returning it at a separate endpoint, then. Alternatively, you can also set the variable globally on index.html so all other html files can access it by putting this before all other script tags: <script>
        const data = {{ data | safe }};
    </script>

Comment: Then, `data` should be accessible by all JS files on the site.

Comment: @Nisala actually breaking down the data into two different routes worked. I'll work with it that way. Thanks for the help! Also for reference in case anyone have similar issues I jsonify my data using this code:

`data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM msa", conn)`
`data_json = data.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')`
`msa_json = Response(response=data_json, status=200, mimetype='application/json')`